# different errno on vs 2010 and 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ace

I have C++ code in a project which behaves differently with Visual Studio 2010 and VS 2015.

```
    if(return_val != 0)
    {
      ACE_OS::set_errno_to_last_error ();
      result->set_error(errno);
    }
```

return_val is the the return value of a prior function which has failed. So the next step is to capture error value.

**In VS 2010**

When result->set_error(errno) is called, while debugging, the control goes to the function _errno() , defined in source \VC\crt\src\dosmap.c.

**In VS 2015**
The source dosmap.c is not found.
The macro expansion for errno must be in a different place I suppose. But the behaviour should be same

Do I need to make any change in the VS settings for 2015?
Any help would be useful.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Is something not working? Why does it matter where `errno` is defined?

Comment: The errno is set to value 2 in VS 2010. Where as in Vs 2015 it is set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed the source files for the library.  This would explain why it can't find the file.

errno is a strange variable, and is thread-local, and macro'ed in both platforms.  What is happening in `ACE_OS::set_errno_to_last_error ();`?

If the function is not setting the errno value, that would explain the behavior differences.

Comment: ACE_OS::set_errno_to_last_error ();  does this                                    errno = ::GetLastError ();                                                                                   Source files for which library? i did a default installation for 2015